# What about "if as a slave" in selichot?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-hashanah-new-year, selichot

On Rosh Hashana, after the shofar blowing during the Musaf repetition, we say "Hayom Harat Olam." In it, we consider 2 possibilities of how Hashem might deal with us -- "im k'vanim" (if as children) and "im k'avadim" (if as slaves). Then we give details about how we should be dealt with in either of those two cases.

But in selichot, after the 13 Middot, we say the paragraph of "k'rachem" which says only "krachem av al banim ken terachem..." As a father is merciful on a son, so should Hashem be merciful towards us.

Why do we, on R"H present 2 possibilities if we can simply instruct God to deal with us as a child? Why do we add "slave" in on Rosh Hashana at all (or, if the optionality if important, why do we drop the slave option elsewhere)?

Comment: Note that we _do_ present both possibilities in _s'lichos_, in the paragraph "_Mache umase_".

Comment: I see that, but then why would it be absent from the K'rachem paragraph? And in the later "Maran Dibeeshmaya" why is slave listed without son?

Comment: A thought - "Hayom Harat Olam" says at the beginning - "Kol Yetzurei olamim", which is a reference to all humanity, not just Jews. For some reason (have to research) this may include the notion that some sector of humanity might be treated as slaves. Selichot service is more specific to Jews. Perhaps, as Jews, we are already considered "avdei Hashem" - slaves of G-d. Thus, it may not necessitate the slave comparison.

Comment: @DanF then you would have to contend with the slave references msh210 and I listed in the above comments.

Comment: @msh210 Where is this paragraph located? Is this at the end near the end of the selichot "tachanun"?

Comment: Be aware that this is probably not the work of a single individual, but rather the outcome of an evolving liturgy incorporating components from many different authors, so this may not be a deliberate distinction.

Comment: @mevaqesh that's what I figured (especially seeing a section in Hebrew vs. Aramaic) but I was wondering if there was an intentional shift in approach between the shofar on R"H and selichot in general.